# Does the military sleep technique have a 96 percent success rate?

Tags: sleep

The [military sleep technique](https://www.industrytap.com/secret-u-s-military-technique-helps-you-sleep-in-two-minutes/46569) is a method to fall asleep within 2 minutes. It is said that the method works (after a number of weeks) for 96% of the people who try it. Is there any scientific research to backup this claim?

Comment: Related on our [skeptics.se] stack a [similar question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41528/relax-and-win-classified-military-method-to-fall-asleep-quick) which has received no answer to date (but a number of duplicates - interest is high).

Comment: @JiminyCricket. That question has been on a busy site like Skeptics for over 4 years and has 5K views, yet not a single answer. That leads me to believe there is no credible evidence and it's just a claim made to sell a book. After all, it's just the stock advice to relax and clear your mind dressed up as some sort of military secret. If it were that simple and 96% effective, virtually nobody would have sleep difficulties.

Comment: I concur. It would seem to indicate a desire for information about effective techniques - perhaps an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). @CareyGregory